# VueJS user mounted() on new click/reset component state?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have on the same page 2 components:
1. Item List
2. Lightbox, classic html lightbox without any additional vuejs components

I pass trought prop my item id to the lightbox, it works, if I click on item I see the correct value.

My idea was to use mounted() to make a request and get additional data on every call but I saw this is not possible and mounted is run only on the page reload.

[image]

Is there a way to reset component state and run mounted on every call?

Comment: Mounted is run every time the _component_ is mounted – which should work fine for your purposes? If not, you could always create a `getAdditionalData()` method which you run inside of mounted, and then also call whenever you need to.

Comment: Post the relevant code please so we can help.

Comment: @Djave can I unmount my component if modalbox closes? I want to show data and make request if I open modalbox.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will make this request for you, that is, every time you click on the item it makes this request, and pass the data to the component through props. If you want to use this function in the mounted, just invoke it using this. Do not leave it tied inside the mounted, causing you to recharge the component every time, but link it through an event.

Example:

```
<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
    <button @click="getData">Get Data</button>
    <button @click="clear">clear</button>
</div>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clear() {
      this.info = null
    },
    getData() {
      axios
        .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        .then(response => {
           this.info = response
        })
      }
    },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hamiltongabriel/nazvruLj/7/